# Messy routing - GET or POST

Tags: http, url-routing

I have this flow but don't know how to deal with it. I think "Forward" button should use GET because it is safe and idempotent but the textarea contains a large amount of text so I think can't put in in URI. I changed to POST.

The OK button on confirmCreateAlbum surely POST.
The flow says When click "Cancel" on confirmCreateAlbum, it returns to nameAlbum with the fields were filled for editing. I put OK button in a form with action="confirmCreateAlbum". The problem is how to back to nameAlbum?

Note: nameAlbum will show errors if the required fields are not provided.

[image]

Comment: I follow the rule: Use `GET` when you want the URL to be unique (like a search box). Use `POST` for all others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no specific length limitation for GET requests in the [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2068.html), browsers impose limits on URI lengths. There are also considerations with some server implementations.

You said the textarea "contains a large amount of text" so it is recommended to use POST in this situation because it won't be subjected to URI limitations.

On to your original question, "The problem is how to back to nameAlbum?"

In your confirmCreateAlbum form, you can actually use two separate forms. A form for the "OK" which the action calls your specified script for confirming, and a form for the "Cancel" which has an action calling your nameAlbum form.

Anther option is getting clever with hidden input fields and passing the data around but that can get messy.

Personally, if it were up to me, I'd be using jQuery/Javascript for confirming form submission. It's a simple client side solution that doesn't require you to leave your original form if "Cancel" is pressed. But that's just me...

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I made two form for "OK" and "Cancel", so the hidden input doubles. xD

Answer (score 1):

I don't think post or get is the problem here.

You can create two form: one with the ok button, post/get to further step; one with the cancel button, post/get to nameAlbum.
Or you can create one form with two button with same name and two different value and post/get to some page. On that page you check the value and redirect to further step or to nameAlbum.

After posting to confirmCreateAlbum, where do you store the data from the textarea?
I assume you store it in the session so in nameAlbum you can fill the data (if there's any) to the field.

And if you can use javascript, you can just handler the next, cancel button with some javascript and avoid some round trip.

Comment: I won't store anything in Session because it is not good programming practice. If I use Session, this problem is easy.